# Azure: If I run a program on a VM through a remote desktop's CLI, does that program still run until completion when I close the CLI?

Tags: python, azure, cloud

I am trying to run a computationally intensive Python program  (which will take several hours) on a virtual machine (VM) through connecting to that virtual machine from a remote desktop's command line interface (CLI), will that Python program continue to run until it finishes, even when I close the CLI?

If not, **how can I guarantee that the program will run until completion**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question, I assume you use the CLI command `az vm run-command invoke` to run the scripts in the remote VM, then [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command#restrictions) is the description:

> You can't cancel a running script.

It means if you start running the script in the remote VM, then the script will run until the task finished, even if you close or cancel the CLI command.

Comment: I believe that is a PowerShell script, not a Python script, right?

Comment: @AdamLee I don't agree. It's a script, any scripts. For example, in Linux, it's a shell script.

Comment: @AdamLee If you want to run the python. I recommend you copy the python script into the VM, and then you can use the shell script to run that python script.

Comment: @AdamLee Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.